# dependent dropdownlist with json and python

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, django

So I am making a dialog panel for my chat bot in django framework. The Dialog panel consists of intent and entities dropdown list and a dialog textarea. The dropdown list will be dependent on my training data which is in json format.

I want the dropdownlist so that if I choose intent, the entities dropdown list create itself automatically and show all the entities related to selected intent.

I have tried and I am able to show intent dropdown but that too had duplicate intents(which i removed using python set function).But I am unable to figure out how to show all entities based on one particular intent.

Help me. Here's my example json:

```
{"rasa_nlu_data": {

"common_examples": [
  {
    "text": "hey", 
    "intent": "greet", 
    "entities": []
  }, 
  {
    "text": "yep", 
    "intent": "affirm", 
    "entities": []
  },
  {
    "text": "i'm looking for a place to eat",
    "intent": "restaurant_search",
    "entities": []
  },
  {
    "text": "i'm looking for a place in the north of town",
    "intent": "restaurant_search",
    "entities": [
      {
        "start": 31,
        "end": 36,
        "value": "north",
        "entity": "location"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "show me chinese restaurants",
    "intent": "restaurant_search",
    "entities": [
      {
        "start": 8,
        "end": 15,
        "value": "chinese",
        "entity": "cuisine"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "bye", 
    "intent": "goodbye", 
    "entities": []
  }
]}}
```

Comment: I downvoted because your question is very badly formatted. The lack of conjunctions, lack of space between sentences, the lack of paragraphs and reference to yourself with a small letter "i" make your question, at least for me, very difficult to read. The example code you've posted is too long and redundant. Please fix your question - it's the least you can do if you're expecting someone to help you with your problem.

Comment: Ok.I have improved formatting to some extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, all you have to do is loop over the items inside `common_examples` and check if the `intent` matches the selected value in the dropdown. If it does, add the `entities` to entities dropdown.

Since you haven't provided much info about your HTML, I'll try to answer with a few assumptions:

1. You've a `select` element with id `intentDropdown` to show intents.
2. You've a `select` element with id `entitiesDropdown` to show entities.
3. You're using jQuery.

The code contains some comments to explain what it does.

```html
<!-- intents dropdown -->
<select id="intentsDrowpdown">
    <!-- intent options-->
</select>

<!-- entities dropdown -->
<select id="entitesDrowpdown"></select>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
var data = {"rasa_nlu_data": { ... }}; // the json data

var totalExamples = data.rasa_nlu_data.common_examples.length; // total items inside common_examples

// listen to the event when selected value in 
// the intent dropdown changes
$("#intentsDropdown").on('change', function() {

    $("#entitiesDropdown").empty(); // clear the previously added entities from entities drowpdown

    var selectedIntent = this.value; // currently selected intent

    // loop over the items in common_examples
    for (var i = 0; i < totalExamples; i++) {

        var currentExample = data.rasa_nlu_data.common_examples[i] // current example in the loop

        // see if the selected intent matches the 
        // intent of the current example in the loop
        if (currentExample.intent == selectedIntent) {

            // if intent matches
            // loop over the items inside entities 
            // of the current example
            for (var j = 0; j < currentExample.entities.length; j++) {
                // add the option in the dropdown
                $("#entitiesDropdown").append($('<option>', {
                    value: currentExample.entities[j].value,
                    text: currentExample.entities[j].entity
                }));
            }

        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Finally, I'd like to bring one thing to your notice. Conside the example below:

```
"entities": [
  {
    "start": 8,
    "end": 15,
    "value": "chinese",
    "entity": "cuisine"
  }
```

The `entities` list has one item in it. And that item has 4 sub-items in it. In  your question, you haven't made it clear if you want to show all the sub-items in one dropdown option (e.g. `start: 8, end: 15, value: chinese, entity: cuisine`) or if you want a separate option for each sub-item.

The JS code that I've posted will create a dropdown option like this:
`<option value="chinese">cuisine</option>`.

If you want to display other items, you can just create another loop and keep adding the items to dropdown.

Comment: Thank you so much.